# How to get response time from curl request (via command-line)

Tags: performance, curl, time, request

How can I capture the response time from a CURL request?

```
curl https://www.google.com
```

Answer (score 37, accepted):

I found this approach in [an article](https://viewsby.wordpress.com/2013/01/07/get-response-time-with-curl/) that returns a value in seconds

```
curl -o /dev/null -s -w %{time_total}\\n  https://www.google.com
```

It outputs something like:

```
0.059
```

Comment: Should be noted this assumes Bash